# what does XXX<U, in T: U> mean in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

what does `TimeoutCoroutine<U, in T: U>` mean in kotlin. I was reading this

```
private class TimeoutCoroutine<U, in T: U>(
    @JvmField val time: Long,
    uCont: Continuation<U> // unintercepted continuation
)
```

but really don't understand what this <U, in T> means. Could someone explain? thanks a lot!

Comment: especially this ```in T```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TimeoutCoroutine is a [generic class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html) who need two types :

- U, it can be whatever you want
- T who extends the U type directly or indirectly (defined by `T: U`)
- the `in` keyword, According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance)

  > It makes a type parameter contravariant, meaning it can only be
  > consumed and never produced.

  So you will be able to use the T type but never create an instance of it or returning it in a method.

For exemple :

```kotlin
class Foo<in T> {
    fun bar(a: T) = a
}
```

the bar function will show you an error saying that this method use the T type with `out` position instead of `in` because you are returning an object who has the T type